# Can an authoritative DNS server tell who is trying to resolve a domain name?

Tags: dns, dns-domain

Let's assume my domain `example.com` has `ns1` record pointed to a random IP address `192.0.2.111`.

When somebody tries to resolve `example.com`, can the dns server at `192.0.2.111` see what IP is trying to resolve that domain name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly. Keep in mind you won't see requests from systems which either have the dns info cached or are using a dns server which has it cached. Likewise if you have someone visiting or attacking your site who is using an external dns server the dns query will likely come from the IP address of the dns server they are using and not the visitor/attackers IP itself. So you will see the query itself but it may come from a public DNS server.

Answer (score 0):

Like Trey says, the IP of the stub resolver (the one starting the DNS query) is not visible. The IP address visible would be the IP address of the DNS recursive server.

Having said that, if you want to make the client IP visible, you can install the DNS resolver (`BIND, djbdns`) on the client itself.

Comment: That or just add a /etc/hosts entry and prioritize that over DNS if it's not already prioritized by default.

Comment: You mean add a static mapping for 192.0.2.111? What if the nameserver for example.com keeps changing. {/etc/hosts} will be hard to maintain.

Comment: sorry not enough context. i was replying in the sense of if you want to make the IP visible. For example if you just wanted to do this to test something. Definitely not a long term solution.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, each DNS request packet has it's origin included. That's how the response is capable of getting the record back to the requester. To learn more about what's in a DNS request packet and how they work take a look here:

http://www.firewall.cx/networking-topics/protocols/domain-name-system-dns/160-protocols-dns-query.html

Comment: I think there may have been a misunderstanding. Note that the DNS server at `62.12.18.180` is not necessarily the one fulfilling the request.

Comment: Problem is, you will never be certain if the *origin* is a client or another DNS server. Probably it's a DNS server asking in name of its client.